# Не работает реконнект к серверу после долгого разрыва связи

Tags: python, сокет

На удаленном распбери крутится код собирающий и передающий данные на сервер. При разрыве соединения идет бесконечное переподключение, но если связи небыло очень долго, около суток например - то процедура переподключение где-то блокируется или висит. Сложно понять что именно произошло. Я подключаюсь по SSH, вижу работающий код, вижу как он собирает данные, но не вижу попыток подключения к серверу. (сбор данных и отправка работают в разных потоках). Если разрыв был не долгим - часик допустим, то нет проблем.

```
 def connectToServer ():
    print("Server: connecting")
    global ServerSock
    try:
        ServerSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        ServerSock.settimeout(10)
        ServerSock.connect((ServerHost, ServerPort))
        ServerSock.settimeout(10)
        print("Server: connected")
    except:
        print("error occured")
        ServerSock.close()
        time.sleep(5)
        connectToServer()



def runServerSending ():
    connectToServer()
    while True:
            try:
                ServerSock.sendall(json.dumps(this.__dict__).encode())
                answer = ServerSock.recv(1024)
                if not answer:
                    raise Exception('Server socket error')
            except:
                print("Server: send data error")
                ServerSock.close()
                connectToServer()
            time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Можно попробовать не оставлять голый `except`, а перехватывать конкретные исключения. Возможно, ситуация немного прояснится.

Comment: @mkkik дело в том что независимо от типа исключения код должен попасть в функцию `connectToServer()`, выводя в консоль "connecting" при каждой попытке.  Этого не происходит. Он где-то блокируется, хотя я выставил таймаут. Функция `close()` может заблокировать код?